# What eyepiece to use for moon?

Tags: telescope

I'm using a 95mm f/8.4 telescope. What's the best eyepiece that I can buy for a very close look at the moon or even planets? I'm a beginner in this field so please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site. Check out these answers: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23968/what-does-it-mean-of-different-eyepieces https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-a-2-inch-eyepiece-versus-a-1-25-inc https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39986/eyepiece-recommendation-for-orion-xt8 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26488/what-kind-of-telescope-eyepieces-is-best-for-viewing-planets-up-close

Comment: Do you have a manual mount or a motorised mount? Also bear in mind that "the best eyepiece that I can buy" will be expensive and unnecessary in a long telescope like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the time, the best eyepiece to use would be the 20 mm lens for seeing the moon. If you want a better view, then you can go for the 10mm. That's what I would do...

Comment: Why would you not want a better view?

Comment: @JamesK sometimes you might not want to have a very close view. Probably for photos or whatever...